# Finding the Location in the User Control

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, devexpress

I have one user control named XtraTreeList(It is combination of the treeview and datagridview) in which I want to get the location of the cell and nodes, but I can not find any property or method for that. Anyone have used it or any idea about that?

Or can I use the graphics approach to find the location of the cell or nodes ? Like, through the text of the cell can I get the location of the cell in the XtraTreeList with the help of the graphics?

Comment: Is this your own user control, or one from a library you're using (that you have no control over)?

Comment: Did you try contacting DevExpress support? I've used DevExpress in the past and their support is excellent.

Comment: I have used. I posted the question same mentioned above in their forum but I did not get any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Rectangle GetCellBounds(TreeList tree, TreeListNode node, int cellIndex)
{
    RowInfo ri = tree.ViewInfo.RowsInfo[node];
    if (ri == null) return Rectangle.Empty;

    CellInfo ci = tree.ViewInfo.RowsInfo[node].Cells[cellIndex] as CellInfo;
    return ci.Bounds
}
```

This function can be used to get the bounds of the cell.